Building PHP with lib in non-standard location
I am trying to compile an old version (5.6.38) of PHP from source, though I think this question may be more about building software where required libs are in a non-standard location than specifically about PHP.
When I run make I am getting the following error:
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.72, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so, may conflict with libicuuc.so.69
Generating phar.php
/tmp/tarballs/php-5.6.38/sapi/cli/php: error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.69: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:375: ext/phar/phar.php] Error 127

My configure looks like this:
CPPFLAGS='-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=1 -DU_DEFINE_FALSE_AND_TRUE=1' PHP_RPATHS=/opt/icu/lib ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6.38 \
    --enable-fpm \
    --with-fpm-user=www-data \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-ftp \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/opt/libjpeg-turbo \
    --with-gd \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-iconv \
    --with-xmlrpc \
    --with-gmp \
    --enable-intl \
    --with-icu-dir=/opt/icu \
    --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-kerberos \
    --with-png-dir=/usr \
    --with-freetype-dir=/opt/freetype \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-mhash \
    --with-tidy=/opt/tidy-html5

I have tried using (as part of the configure command):
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/opt/icu/lib -R/opt/icu/lib -L/opt/icu/lib"

and various variations on that, but always the same error on make.
The only way I can get it to compile without the error is by running
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/icu/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" make

But I assume that while that will allow make to complete, it is not fixing the actual problem and when php was run it would still be looking for the icu lib in the system location rather than the non-standard location where I want it to be looking.
Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get it to compile with using the icu lib in a non-standard location like this?

Got it working now. The solution to this was not in using LDFLAGS or PHP_RPATHS or anything like that, but simply setting CFLAGS='-Wl,--disable-new-dtags' during configure. I'm not sure exactly how it works, but my understanding is that it prevents runtime library paths being used in preference to the compile time paths.
